# Check if a JavaScript variable type has keys

Tags: javascript, for-loop, types

I want to pass some data through a `for...in` loop. I need to check if the data type of `data` (which is unknown until runtime) makes sense to run through that loop first. All of `Array`, `Object`, and `String` are valid, but if `data instanceof String` then `data[i]` is still valid and returns the character in `data` at position `i`. I only want to get entire values (i.e. other scalars and objects), not parts of strings. I'm not sure if there are data types other than `Array` and `Object` that can contain multiple values and therefore make sense to loop over.

What's a good test for such an object? This is what I've got so far, but I don't know if it covers all cases.

```js
if (typeof data === "object" && (data instanceof Array || data instanceof Object)) {
  for (let i in data) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I've also looked at [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterable_protocol), but `Object`s aren't iterable, only `Array`s.

Comment: "This is what I've got so far, but I don't know if it covers all cases." If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: `Objects aren't iterable` In "normal" use the properties of an object aren't usually iterated over.  You grab their properties by name and do specific things with each.

Comment: In general your question feels a little [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Where are these unknown inputs coming from and what is it you're actually trying to accomplish by iterating their keys?

Answer (score 0):

Given that Object.keys function is safe to pass any data type

```
Object.keys(1) // []
Object.keys('f') // ['0']
Object.keys(false) // []
Object.keys(new Date()) // []
Object.keys(BigInt("123456789012345678901234567890")) // []
Object.keys({foo: 1}) // ['foo']
Object.keys(['foo', 'bar']) // ['0', '1']
```

And [MDN claims](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) Object.keys is synonymous with the underworking of for..in... You should be safe attempt to iterate over any object without the test and non-qualifying data types will result in a noop scenario.

Now, a more explicit check for your requirements would be as follows:

```
if (typeof data !== "string" || !(data instanceof String)){ ... }
```

This check would permit all values other than string types and String object instances to enter the for loop.

It is more readable since it says which of the for...in type candidates you want to exclude. And that should address your speculation as to which data types are valid candidates in a for..in iteration.

Comment: I like it! Note that `String` objects behave just like `string`s but are actually `object`s, so `!(typeof data === "string" || data instanceof String)` or equivalent is needed.

Comment: Great point, I updated my answer to include this edge case.

Answer (score 0):

What about just

```
if (typeof data === "object")
```

This covers any potential secret iterable structures that you might have to handle, and excludes all numbers, strings, undefineds, etc [list here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: `data = new String; if (typeof data === "object") { /* This gets executed */ }`

Comment: `data = new String` - nobody uses this, [see warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#string_primitives_and_string_objects).  Exactly how general purpose do you need this to be, and why?